# Android creating a Spotify like slider menu

Tags: android, menu, slider

I am making an app that should implement a slider menu like the one in Spotify (where you slide the triangle in the middle to show the current playing song). The problem is I can't seem to figure out a decent method of doing this. I tried it with a Facebook like menu I found [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270319-how-to-create-a-slide-in-menulist-like-in-facebook-app/).

However that just provides me with 2 linear layouts which are placed next to each other and are basically stretched or unstretched when expanding the menu. This gives some layout issues when expanding/collapsing (all items are placed below each other in the linearlayout when expanding and are quietly moved into the right place when collapsing the menu again).

In Spotify on the other hand it seems as if the layouts are on top of each other when the menu is expanded. This seems like a much cleaner way. However I have no idea on how to tackle this and Google doesn't really provide a lot of answers. Physically sliding the menu up isn't necessary, just getting the layouts on top of each other with some sliding animation on clicking the menu button.

Sorry for the long post, it seemed necessary to specify the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to re-invent a view or do anything fancy to get this functionality. Its called **[`SlidingDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)** and is already available in the framework. Read [this](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-damn-that-sliding-drawer/) and [this](https://mobibear.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/android-slidingdrawer-with-custom-view/) or watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OhGkg_XT3o) video.